# How to add a path for "libeay32.lib" at the solution level on VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to build a solution , but I'm getting the following linker error :

> "error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libeay32.lib'".

I have the library in the source code but I can't find a way to put it in the solution.
Any help would be appreciated

I found a way to add the library at the project level but i want to add it at the solution level

Comment: Linker settings are always per project. There's no way to add them at the solution level.

Comment: you can use a props file to specify common settings https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcxproj-file-structure?view=msvc-170

Comment: You can add a `#pragma comment(lib, "libeay32.lib")` line to a header file that all your projects use; there is likely a `libeay32.h` (or similar) header for the stuff the library contains, although modifying a 3rd-party header is probably not recopmmended.

Comment: OP: Can you clarify whether you're using Visual Studio (in which case your title should have "VS2015" rather than "VC2015") or VS Code? There is a pending edit that has added the `visual-studio-code` tag, and I think that is likely incorrect.

Comment: @AdrianMole, I'm sorry , you are right it is vs2015

Comment: OK - So why did you "Approve" the edit that added an incorrect tag? That tag should ***not*** be used for questions about Visual Studio! VS Code is a completely different IDE/package.

Comment: @AdrianMole, Tag changed

Answer (score 0):

**Linker settings** (as well as compiler settings) in Visual Studio are always **per project**.
There is no way to add them in the solution level.

If you would like to share settings between several projects, then as [@
AlanBirtles commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76967742/how-to-add-a-path-for-libeay32-lib-at-the-solution-level-on-vs2015#comment135683526_76967742), you can create a **property-sheet** and add it to the relevant project(s).

From MS documentation for VS2015:

> To create a property sheet:
>
> 1. On the menu bar, choose View > Property Manager or View > Other Windows > Property Manager. The Property Manager opens.
> 2. To define the scope of the property sheet, select the item to which it applies. This item can be a particular configuration, or another
>    property sheet. Open the shortcut menu for this item and then choose
>    Add New Project Property Sheet. Specify a name and location.
> 3. In Property Manager, open the new property sheet and then set the properties you want to include.

See more about it here: [**VS2015: Share or reuse Visual Studio project settings**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=msvc-140).